# Pull random rows from another file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an Auditing spreadsheet that pulls 5% of the rows from another spreadsheet and copy/pastes them into the "Audit Spreadsheet." So far I've figured out how to do the random pulling via:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Random20()
Randomize 'Initialize Random number seed
Dim MyRows() As Integer    ' Declare dynamic array.
Dim numRows, percRows, nxtRow, nxtRnd, chkRnd, copyRow As Integer
'Determine Number of Rows in Sheet1 Column A
  numRows = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Get 20% of that number
   percRows = numRows * 0.2
'Allocate elements in Array
    ReDim MyRows(percRows) 
'Create Random numbers and fill array
 For nxtRow = 1 To percRows
getNew:
'Generate Random number
  nxtRnd = Int((numRows) * Rnd + 1)
  'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
   For chkRnd = 1 To nxtRow
 'Get new number if Duplicate is found
        If MyRows(chkRnd) = nxtRnd Then GoTo getNew
       Next
'Add element if Random number is unique
      MyRows(nxtRow) = nxtRnd
 Next
'Loop through Array, copying rows to Sheet2
  For copyRow = 1 To percRows
   Sheets(1).Rows(MyRows(copyRow)).EntireRow.Copy _
     Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

I'm looking for a way to adapt that so the user selects the file they want to pull from, and it automatically populates their own Excel spreadsheet for auditing purposes.

Also, there are two header rows.

Comment: What row does the data start on in the workbooks to be audited? Is there a header row?

Comment: Yes. there are two header rows. I was just about to add that to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's all you need:

```
Sub GetRandomRows()
    PULLPERCENT = 0.05
    Dim i&, j&, k&, n&, r, s, v, wb As Workbook
    s = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
    If s <> False Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
        n = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        s = ""
        Randomize
        Do
            j = Int(n * Rnd + 1)
            If InStr(s, "." & j) = 0 Then
                s = s & "." & j
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Loop Until (k > n * PULLPERCENT)
        r = Split(s, ".")
        For i = 1 To n * PULLPERCENT
            v = wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(2 + r(i)).EntireRow
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1).EntireRow = v
        Next
        wb.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, that one is giving me an error "Subscript out of range" at
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(16).Cells(i, 1).EntireRow = v

Comment: So, what this one is doing now is opening up the other excel quickly then closing it without pasting anything into the Audit Excel.

Comment: Ok. So this time it copied and pasted row 1, 2 and 5 and missed a lot of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think will do what you need:

```
Sub Audit()

Dim otherWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim fileName As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim rowNumbers As Object
Dim auditNumber As Long

Set rowNumbers = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")

If Not LCase(fileName) = "false" Then
    Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

    auditNumber = otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).Find(What:="*", After:=otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1), _
           Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row * 0.2 '// 0.2 = 20%

    rowNumbers.Add WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, auditNumber)

    While rowNumbers.Count < auditNumber
        y = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        If Not rowNumbers.Contains(y) Then rowNumbers.Add y
    Wend

    For i = 0 To rowNumbers.Count - 1
        x = x + 1
        otherWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(rowNumbers(i)).EntireRow.Copy _
           Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1)
    Next

End If
```

Comment: auditNumber isn't defined, also, i'm not seeing where it checks to make sure it didn't copy a duplicate row.

Comment: Did a last minute edit, didn't spot it! See edit above :)

Comment: `make sure it didn't copy a duplicate row` <-- didn't spot that, give me a min

Comment: There you go, uses an `ArrayList` object and the `.Contains()` method to ensure unique numbers are selected.

Comment: Now its telling me Unable to get the RandBetween property of the WOrksheetFunction class @ rowNumbers.Add WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, auditNumber)

Comment: Are you actually running this from Excel? `RandBetween` is a worksheet function - works fine on my computer

Comment: Made another edit, for some reason I came to 0.05 for 20% instead of 0.2 (d'oh!)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, see if it works after the last edit - if `UsedRange.Rows.Count * 0.05` was less than 3 for some reason it would have errored.

Comment: This time it just overwrote the excel file I was trying to pull the data from, while leaving the Audit excel sheet blank.

Comment: Edited to copy rows to the workbook that the code is running from.

Comment: Made a final edit to get last row of data in the sheet, rather than the count of UsedRange rows.